# BS 3 getting data attribute value when a link is clicked and tab on show

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I am using BS3 and have tabs like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"> 
    <a id="tab-1" href="#annual_summary" data-toggle="tab">Annual Summary </a> 
  </li>
  <li> 
    <a id="tab-2" href="#monthly_summary" data-toggle="tab">Monthly Summary 
    </a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I have a link like this in the first tab:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn default btn-xs default button-action" 
   data-id="1" 
   data-year="2014" 
   data-month="January" 
   data-tab-destination="tab-2">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Monthly Summary
</a>
```

When a someone clicks on the above link, it moves to the second tab. `data-tab-destination="tab-2"` with this jquery code

```
 //move to tab 2 
  $("a[data-tab-destination]").on('click', function() {
    var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab-destination');
    $("#" + tab).click();
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 500);
  });
```

And in `tab-2` I have this html markup:

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
  <p class="header-title">Year:
    <span class="header-text" id="header_year"></span>
  </p>
  <p class="header-title">Month:
    <span class="header-text" id="header_month"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

And what I want to achieve is when the link is clicked, and moved to the second tab, I want to get the data attribute value `data-year="2014" data-month="January"` and put the value in the `#header_year, #header_month`.

I created this js code

```
//TAB ON SHOW
  $("a[href='#monthly_summary']").on('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {
              var div = $(event.relatedTarget)
   var id = div.data('id');
   var year = div.data('year');
   var month = div.data('month');
   var tab = $(this)

   tab.find('#id').attr("value", id);
   tab.find('#header_year').html(year);
   tab.find('#header_month').html(month);
  });
```

But doesnt seem to work :(

Please help meeee..... Thanks!!

**UPDATED**

Here is my working code:

```
  var id;
  var year;
  var month;

    //move to tab 2 when assignment button clicked
      $("a[data-tab-destination]").on('click', function() {

        id = $(this).data('id');
        year =  $(this).data('year');
        month = $(this).data('month');
        var tab = $(this).attr('data-tab-destination');
        $("#" + tab).click();
        $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
      });

      //TAB ON SHOW
      $("a[href='#monthly_summary']").on('show.bs.tab', function() {
           $('#id').attr("value", id);
           $('#header_year').html(year);
           $('#header_month').html(month);
      });
```

Comment: @jperelli still doesnt work with `var year = div.attr('data-year')` when I alert `year` it returned `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `div.data('year')` instead of `div.data('year_filtered');`

Try also using `div.attr('data-year')` instead of `div.data('year')` (look carefully at `attr`)

---

**Edit**:
how about putting an id to the link

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn default btn-xs default button-action" 
   id="a-tab-1"
   data-id="1" 
   data-year="2014" 
   data-month="January" 
   data-tab-destination="tab-2">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Monthly Summary
</a>
```

and then using it to get the data in your js

```
// var div = $(event.relatedTarget)
var div = $('#a-tab-1')
```

Comment: my bad I forgot to change to month and year. But still not working.... I have edited my code above :(